# Ambiguous between system.web.mvc.dll and solution_name.dll when using master page on a razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, master-pages

I've been trying to implement [this](http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2011/01/07/Using-Razor-Pages-with-WebForms-Master-Pages.aspx) solution to have a razor view page that makes use of an asp master page. The problem I'm encountering is that the master page cannot inherit the MVC ViewMasterPage:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
```

> Parser Error Message: The type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage' is ambiguous: it could come from assembly 'C:\Projects\OpenDataPortal\OpenDataPortal\bin\System.Web.Mvc.DLL' or from assembly 'C:\Projects\OpenDataPortal\OpenDataPortal\bin\OpenDataPortal.DLL'. Please specify the assembly explicitly in the type name.

I inspected this `ViewMasterPage` with .NET Reflector and determined that it contains all the Html helpers etc. that are used on Razor pages. Thus, this should allow me to do the following on the RazorView.aspx page that uses this master page as in the solution (the Html helper and ViewBag):

```
<% Html.RenderPartial((string) ViewBag._ViewName); %>
```

I also determined that there should be nothing wrong with my MVC assembly in the web.config:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

I'm also not sure whether having a code-behind and/or designer for the master page and/or RazorView.aspx page would cause any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually what you are using instead of actual MVC master page is aspx which is having a code behind so for example if my master page is `site.master` I would go to its code behind(`my case its .vb)` and add

```
Public Class SiteMaster
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage
```

Now in the voew you can just inherit your Master page class as

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Project.SiteMaster" %>
```

Comment: How is this going to help? You've just moved the error from one location to other.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the other DLL also contains types from `System.Web.Mvc` namespace (most likely they did an ILMerge while publishing their assembly, not sure why though). So you need to remove the ambiguity by providing full assembly name in your `Inherits`:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage, System.Web.Mvc, version=5.2.2.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=31bf3856ad364e35"
```